# ResourcesNotFoundException when trying to read from resource file

Tags: android, resources

I have a strange Exception when I try to parse an xml file which is embedded in my recourses.

I'm initializing a XmlResourceParser with one of my resource-files:

```
XmlResourceParser parser = context.getResources().getXml(R.raw.anniversaries);
```

This code gives no compiler warnings and was generated with autocompletion in eclipse.

When I run this code I get this Exception:

> 10-23 14:33:58.514: E/AndroidRuntime(953): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 10-23
>   14:33:58.514: E/AndroidRuntime(953):
>   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File
>   res/raw/anniversaries.xml from xml type xml resource ID #0x7f060000
>   10-23 14:33:58.514: E/AndroidRuntime(953):    at
>   android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2351)

The only source for this evil I can imagine of may be fact that I have two `raw` folders at the moment for localization issues.

One folder is called `raw`, the other one `raw-de`. Both contain the same xml-file at the moment.

Any idea what the problem could be and how to solve it?

*Edit:
I moved the xml-files from the raw-folders to the xml-folders and now it works. Whats the problem with the raw-folders?*

Comment: I get the same exception after cleaning and rebuilding the app

Comment: Did you try temporarily removing the raw folder with localization to see if that's really not the problem?

Comment: I deleted the 'raw-de' folder but the exception is the same :(

Comment: Try to move your xml to xml folder. I think it can get xmls from raw folder.

Comment: Moving the files to the xml-folder worked. But should'nt it also work with the raw-folder?